# Django ecommerce modeling- how to model product/service options?

Tags: django, django-models, schema

I am currently facing a dilemma where we are creating a service which can be used for billing or ecommerce-type applications where products and services are modeled and can be sold.

I am working on Services, which have ServiceOptions. The Services are assigned to Businesses, which will each contain a unique combination of Services and ServiceOptions.

Accounting for the unique requirement, I have represented a Service (which all possible ServiceOptions point to as a foreign key relation) assigned to a Business by creating a BusinessService containing the options that create the Service variant.

However, the issue is that I am currently unable to understand how to model the relationship between ServiceOptions and the BusinessService. My current service models are as follows:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=450)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class ServiceOption(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=450)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class BusinessService(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price_override = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Here we create a unique entity tying the Service to the Business, but this is not sufficient to represent the ServiceOptions, as the BusinessService.service.serviceoption relation contains ALL possible options, not those specific to the business.

I have considered structuring the models as follows:

```
class ServiceOption(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=450)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class BusinessService(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service_options = models.ManyToManyField(ServiceOption)
    price_override = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

This would create generic ServiceOptions, only related to a Service through the BusinessService model. The obvious issue here is any ServiceOption could be added to any BusinessService and create invalid pairings such as adding an option named 'Phone Lines' to an 'Email Hosting' service. This could also present an issue if something about the ServiceOption was changed, where that value would affect all services referencing it.

This same issue would be present creating a BusinessServiceOption table with the same strategy.

The more thought I give to this, the more it seems there may not be a perfect solution, but in essence what I am aiming to do is create a model like the following:

```
class BusinessServiceOption(models.Model):
    business_service = models.ForeignKey(BusinessService, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service_option = models.ForeignKey(ServiceOption, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This would ideally somehow constrain service_options to only the ServiceOptions that reference the underlying Service through the BusinessService object.

Is what I am aiming for achievable? Is my entire approach wrong? Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.